# How to set initial SelectedItem in DropDownList inside ListView EditItemTemplate?

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview

I have a ListView control with DDL in its EditItemTemplate:

```
<asp:ListView ID="ListView1" ItemType="Project.Models.Product" 
              SelectMethod="GetProducts" runat="server" >
    <EditItemTemplate>
        <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="ProducerDDL" 
                          DataValueField="ProducerId" 
                          DataTextField="Name" 
                          SelectMethod="GetProducers" />
    </EditItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```

`Project.Models.Product` contains property `Producer`. 
So the question is: how to set actual `Producer` of the edited `Product` item as the selected item of `ProducerDDL`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So it seems the solution is just using `Bind()` the proper way:

```
<asp:DropDownList SelectedValue='<%# Bind("Producer.ProducerId") %>' />
```

as the binding context is my `Product` item.